# SDWebImage : UIImageView to adjust size by the size of downloaded images

Tags: uiimageview, iso, sdwebimage

I try to download image into my custom tableviewcell but the problem is these images are varied by width and height.  So how to create the UIImageView that can adjust the width and height per the image downloaded ?

I am using SDWebImage framework to help the caching and download.  and I put the setImageWithURL code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 113 of SDWebImageDecoder.m, replace the bitmapInfo value *kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast* with *kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst* and voilà!